# volume shadow copy vs data protection manager

Tags: c++, backup, shadow-copy

trying to implement a VSS backup solution similar to what is described here:
[Volume Shadow Copy (VSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692848/volume-shadow-copy-vss)

there is a new offering called data protection manager:
http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/dataprotectionmanager/en/us/overview.aspx

how different is this from VSS based solution?

does it solve the problem of implementing a VSS writer?

Answer (score 0):

DPM comes as a part of System Center and it makes use of VSS writers. In other words it is dependent on VSS service. You will face issues if VSS fails, DPM backup wont work. It also makes use of application writers for application specific backups(like MS SQL DB and Exchange Mailbox)

DPM is a complete backup solution of almost all Microsoft platforms be it VMS, Sharepoint,SQL DB, MAILBOXES, FILES. It also has backup to Azure and Backup to tapes to meet short term and Long term goals.