# How to copy Windows/System32 using C++

Tags: c++, copy, directory

I have to build a copy tool project. I want to copy/clone the entire `C:` drive. I tried using `SHFileOperation()` and `IFileOperation`, but they allow me to copy files that are not system files only.

Can anyone suggest any API or method to complete the task?

Comment: You could look into [Volume Shadow Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692848/volume-shadow-copy-vss).

Comment: That's not in general possible unless you boot the OS from a different drive.  If you don't then you'll find that lots of files on C: will have a hard lock on them.

Comment: actually, I am looking for something like hobocopy; tool can copy system and registry file while they are working. if anyone suggest me apis or a sample code would quite helpful for me.